# Linking SDL 2 VS Code project with Easy C++ Project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, sdl-2

I created a fresh project in Visual Studio Code with Easy C++ Project.
I tried to link in SDL2 (downloaded the source from their website), but it feels like I'm missing a step?

IE `SDL_Main.h` is not found? So I guess it either badly linked or I need to build it? I'm really not familiar with  build/make/project setup usually work in V Studio in a already setup project...

Can someone guide me?

[image: Setup]

[image: Compile logs]

[image: main.cpp]

Comment: Instead of the source, try the development libraries...  The source is if you want to make changes to the way the SDL works.

Comment: Instead of trying to guess the right way, look for some tutorials.

Comment: Well i tried, that's why i ended up here. I didn't succeed. So useful.

Answer (score 0):

after installing the library and setting up the path in properties.json, use
    #include 
instead of what you used.